# Python question on how these two lists are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a weird problem where I have 2 seemingly identical lists and yet using one gets one answer and using the other gets a second answer even though they are the same list, just generated by different methods.

try the program below and see that b and c are the same. (print outs on line 8)

**then when using b's on line 11,13 and 16 we get an answer of 0.
using c's on line 11,13 and 16 we get an answer of 6.**

i've tried this on numerous compliers and cannot understand what aspect python is using to differenciate from b and c.  Try it yourself by copying and pasting below(Thanks in advance for helping out!):

```
def oddCells(n, m, indices):
    a = [0]*m
    b =[]
    for every in range(n):
        b +=[a]
    c = [ [0] * m for i in range(n) ]
    result = 0
    print(b,"|",c,b == c)
    for e in indices:
        for i in range(m):
            b[e[0]][i] += 1
        for j in range(n):
            b[j][e[1]] += 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if b[i][j] %2 != 0:
                result +=1
    return(result)
W =[[0,1],[1,1]]
print(oddCells(2,3,W))
```

############SECOND VERSION TO COMPARE####################################

```
def oddCells(n, m, indices):
    a = [0]*m
    b =[]
    for every in range(n):
        b +=[a]
    c = [ [0] * m for i in range(n) ]
    result = 0
    print(b,"|",c,b == c)
    for e in indices:
        for i in range(m):
            c[e[0]][i] += 1
        for j in range(n):
            c[j][e[1]] += 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if c[i][j] %2 != 0:
                result +=1
    return(result)
W =[[0,1],[1,1]]
print(oddCells(2,3,W))
```

Comment: `b` is a list that contains *the same list* `n` times. `c`, on the other hand, is a list that contains `n` distinct lists.  `b +=[a]` sort of indirect way of doing `b.append(a)` which simply adds *the same list* to `b` over and over again. Consider, `a = []; b = []; b.append(a); b.append(a); a.append(42); print(b)`

Comment: (my comment was before you edited in the example)wow that is an excellent example, I had originally used b.append(a) but i changed it thinking that would fix it.  I had no idea that later code could alter a list in that way that is very very strange to me, but it definitely illustrated the problem of how b and c were different thank you!

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html it is very helpful

Comment: Also, be careful using `*`. Consider, `data = [[]]*3; data[0] = 42; print(data)`, IOW, the repetition operator doesn't copy the items contained in the list, perhaps put another way, `[x]*3` is equivalent to `[x, x, x]`

Comment: def oddCells(n, m, indices):
    b =[]
    for every in range(n):
        a = [0]*m
        b +=[a]
    c = [ [0] * m for i in range(n) ]
    result = 0
    print(b,"|",c,b == c)

Comment: moving a=[0*m] inside the for loop fix the problem and now everything is very clear. Thanks a ton for your help